# parse dashboard changing user's password

Tags: swift, parse-server, parse-dashboard

Working on a new app and have some testers using it. One of them forgot their password and my partner made a mistake and changed the password for that user to something in plaintext from mLab. We usually make password changes (for now, until we build the password reset logic) in parse dashboard directly: enter in a password in plaintext, it's hashed automatically.

When we try to load the User collection in Parse Dashboard to make the change to the password and hash it accordingly, the User collection doesn't load. The other collections load just fine though.

I've tried updating my parse dashboard version since I was running a slightly older version, but that didn't work either.

Any advice on a fix?

Comment: Set the password to a known hash in mongo, so the dashboard can load, then reset the password using your normal method.

Comment: Hey William - Thanks for your suggestion. Turns out the reason was that I manually (through Mongo directly) created a dictionary and I used key-value pairs (i.e. career : software engineer) for one of the fields in the collection which caused the issue with the loading of the collection. It was confusing because I could see the data in Mongo and in my application, but I didn't discover it until I needed to change a hashed pwd.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!